# how to connect Salesforce OAuth to another salesforce org

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce, visualforce

I have created a POST method REST service and trying to Ajax call the service through sforce.connection.remoteFunction from JavaScriptin a visualforce page.

```
 var request_url = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
 var result = sforce.connection.login("myloginid@mymail.com", "mypassword+mysecurityToken");
```

here the login id, password and security token is different from the id and password which i have to use into login to salesfroce account

```
 var sessionId= sforce.connection.sessionId;  
 sforce.connection.init(sessionId, request_url);

 sforce.connection.remoteFunction({

 url : request_url,
 type : "post",
 async : false,
 requestHeaders: {"Authorization":"Bearer "+sessionId, "Content-Type":"application/json","Connection":"Keep-Alive"},

            data :requestData,          
            onSuccess : function(response) {
                console.log(success);
            },
            onFailure: function(response) {
               console.log(response.responseText);

                 }
        });
```

But the response was Error 401 Unauthorized. Is there anything I'm missing in the request?

i have seen two solutions for this :-

1.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17382/apex-rest-api-call-from-javascript-via-ajax-toolkit?rq=1

2.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13607/how-to-call-apex-rest-api-from-javascript

but these solutions are not working for me.Please help me out..